# Ordering of resultset

Tags: mysql, sql

I am ordering my resultset by a column with a string, and I want it to be ordered in alphabetical order. When I order it by the column it seems to order by string length and not alphabetically.

This is my current sql query:

```
SELECT clientName FROM requests ORDER By clientName ASC
```

I have also tried:

```
SELECT clientName FROM requests ORDER By SUBSTR( clientName, 1, 1 ) ASC
```

clientName is a VARCHAR

I want the resultset to be ordered alphabetically for this one (I am having a similar problem with a column with an int that also seems to be ordered by length and not numerically).

The create statement for the table:

```
CREATE TABLE Requests (
    reqID INT(11) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    foilType VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    numberKits INT(11) NOT NULL,
    dueDate date,
    clientName VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    deliveryAddress VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    quoteNo VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    priority INT(11) NOT NULL,
    comments VARCHAR(100),
    contract BLOB,
    stat VARCHAR(25),
    reference INT(11),
    date_updated DATETIME
 );
```

When I have three different clients such as ABC, BC, DEFG the result of the query is in the order: DEFG, ABC, BC.

Update: SQL fiddle is giving me the wanted result I must be going wrong somewhere else, I will edit my post if i figure it out. Apologies for the bad question.

Comment: Create fiddle with your data [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/).

Comment: Show us some sample data and the wanted result. (Formatted text, no images.)

Comment: `ORDER BY clientName` is the correct approach.

Comment: SELECT clientName FROM requests ORDER By clientName ->why this query is not working ?

Comment: @OnkarMusale the query works but it is ordering the strings by length and not alphabetically

Comment: Is it MySQL, show how your output is coming. send screenshot

Comment: SELECT clientName FROM requests ORDER BY length(clientName); - this is real query to get results by string length. what's the difference you're getting

Comment: @quickSwap yeah it is MySQL, I am not allowed to embed pictures in my post...

Comment: @AlfieDanger send screenshot of your output for your query you are having problem with.

Comment: @quickSwap sadly i am not allowed to add a picture to my post

Comment: Just in case try this: `SELECT clientName FROM requests ORDER By trim(clientName) ASC`

Comment: Create [sqlfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/) for sample data then. Because whatever you are saying is myth for all of us.

Comment: @quickSwap haha ok i will make a sqlfiddle

Comment: @quickSwap ok the sqlfiddle is giving me the result I want. I must be doing something wrong somewhere else in my program. Thanks for your help I am going to try figure out where I am going wrong. Sorry for the unanswerable question. Should I delete this question now? I am new to stackoverflow...

Comment: @AlfieDanger What's the problem in showing only clientName, I see its just the name. what else?

Comment: @quickSwap I also order a resultset by the reference and i want it to be ordered by numerical size but again it seems to take the length... I must be doing something wrong outside my sql query since sqlfiddle is giving me the wanted result

Comment: Corrupt index perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my mistake was that I was using a HashSet to store all the values of the clientName so there was no problem with the resultset but rather when I looped through the HashSet. I solved it now by using a LinkedHashSet